# sum up multiple jquery click events

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am having a hard time to sum up multiple events into one function in order to reduce the code.
I have a simple click function on a few images where the img src is being toggled onclick.

The HTML

```
<a href="#!">
    <img src="image_1.png" style="opacity: 1;" class="preiskreis_1" />
</a>
<a href="#!">
    <img src="image_2.png" style="opacity: 1;" class="preiskreis_2" />
</a>
<a href="#!">
    <img src="image_2.png" style="opacity: 1;" class="preiskreis_3" />
</a>
```

The JS

```
    $('a .preiskreis_1').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'preis_1.png')
            ? 'finanz_1.png'
            : 'preis_1.png';
        $(this).fadeTo(450,0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src).fadeTo(100,1);
        });
    }
});

$('a .preiskreis_2').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'preis_2.png')
            ? 'finanz_2.png'
            : 'preis_2.png';
        $(this).fadeTo(450,0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src).fadeTo(100,1);
        });
    }
});

$('a .preiskreis_3').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'preis_3.png')
            ? 'finanz_3.png'
            : 'preis_3.png';
        $(this).fadeTo(450,0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src).fadeTo(100,1);
        });
    }
});
```

Now what I want to accomplish is to sum that code in the js all up in one function. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ft8et2o6/1/)

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<a href="#!">
    <img src="http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_1.png" alt="Kauf oder Finanzierung" style="opacity: 1;" class="preiskreis" />
</a>

<br>
<a href="#!">
    <img src="http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_2.png" alt="Kauf oder Finanzierung" style="opacity: 1;" class="preiskreis" />
</a>

<br>
<a href="#!">
    <img src="http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_3.png" alt="Kauf oder Finanzierung" style="opacity: 1;" class="preiskreis" />
</a>

<script>
    $('a .preiskreis').on({
        'click': function() {
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            var a = src.split('/');
            var n = a[a.length-1];
            if (n.substr(0,5) == 'preis') {
                n = n.replace('preis','finanz');
            }
            else {
                n = n.replace('finanz','preis');
            }
            src = 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/'+n;
            $(this).fadeTo(450,0, function() {
                $(this).attr('src', src).fadeTo(100,1);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

In this case we find the image file name then check for it contains preis. If yes, replace it to fianz else replace it to preis. So it keeps your naming.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ft8et2o6/6/

Some additional note:
You don't have to put the images into `<a>` tags to be clickable. To show the user that it's clickable, use a `cursor: pointer;` style.

Comment: Thank you mate, this looks really good to me. I will try to use it

Answer (score 0):

you could store the only variable thing in a html atribute

check this out:

```
<a href="#!">
    <img src="http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_1.png" alt="Kauf oder Finanzierung" style="opacity: 1;" class="preiskreis" data-id="1" />
</a>




$('a .preiskreis').on({
    'click': function() {
        num = $(this).attr('data-id');
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_'+num+'.png')
            ? 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/finanz_'+num+'.png'
            : 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_'+num+'.png';
        $(this).fadeTo(450,0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src).fadeTo(100,1);
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ft8et2o6/2/

Answer (score 0):

First you can put a common class on the `img` elements, I used `preiskreis`, to which you can attach a single click handler. Then you can use the `index()` of the parent `a` element to get related image. Try this:

```
$('a .preiskreis').on({
    'click': function() {
        var index = $(this).closest('a').index('a') + 1;
        var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_' + index + '.png')
            ? 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/finanz_' + index + '.png'
            : 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_' + index + '.png';
        $(this).fadeTo(450, 0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src).fadeTo(100, 1);
        });
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ft8et2o6/3/)

Comment: The problem with that, if I remove one image but keep the names, or use any other numbering method, then the index will not represent the correct image filename.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the element position.

```
$('a').on('click', 'img', function(e) {

var index = $(this).index('img')+1;
var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_'+index+'.png')
            ? 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/finanz_'+index+'.png'
            : 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_'+index+'.png';

        $(this).fadeTo(450,0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src).fadeTo(100,1);
        });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/ft8et2o6/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough for a hint

```
$('a img').on('click',function(){
    var src=$(this).attr('src');
    if(src=='image_1.png')
    {
        //your code 
    }
    else if(src=='image_1.png')
    {

    }
    else if(src=='image_3.png')
    {

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to refactor your code adding the same class for  elements like this:

```
<a href="#!">
    <img src="http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_1.png" 
         alt="Kauf oder Finanzierung" style="opacity: 1;" 
         class="preiskreis" data-image-index="1" />
</a>

<br>

<a href="#!">
    <img src="http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_2.png" 
         alt="Kauf oder Finanzierung" style="opacity: 1;" 
         class="preiskreis" data-image-index="2" />
</a>

<br>

<a href="#!">
    <img src="http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/preis_3.png"    
         alt="Kauf oder Finanzierung" style="opacity: 1;" 
         class="preiskreis" data-image-index="3" />
</a>
```

Also, note that I gave all of the elements a data-image-index value to get the suffix of the image, which is always the same in your demo.

After that, you can write the following code:

```
$(".preiskreis").on({
    'click': function() {

        var element = $(this);

        var imageIndex = element.data("image-index");
        var indexExt = imageIndex.toString() + '.png';
        var hornungImagesUrl = 'http://hornung.eprospekt.info/assets/images/';

        var imageSource = hornungImagesUrl + 'preis_' indexExt;
        var finanzImg = hornungImagesUrl + 'finanz_'+ indexExt;
        var preisImg = hornungImagesUrl + 'preis_' + indexExt;

        var src = (element.attr('src') == imageSource) ? finanzImg : preisImg;

        $(this).fadeTo(450,0, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src).fadeTo(100,1);
        });
    }
});
```

Check out [this gist](http://jsfiddle.net/ft8et2o6/11/) for testing purposes.

Hope it helps,